# Screenshot is not attached to report but available in 'allure-results' folder or failure Specs screenshot

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, allure

In Allure Reporters [with Protractor], The screenshot which is being taken is only at the end of the test. Due to which the screenshot which is showing in the Allure Reports are of login page only and not of the application once user logged in.

Here is the code, I am using to generate the Allure Reports.

```
allureReporterSetup: function() {
    const AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        resultsDir: 'allure-results'

    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
        })
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
    onPrepare() {
    var originalAddExpectationResult = jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult;
    jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult = function () {
        if (!arguments[0]) {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                    return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                }, 'image/png')();
            })
        }
        return originalAddExpectationResult.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        resultsDir: 'allure-results',
    }));
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rao, this really helped. Solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AQA i glad it helped you , please can u mark as solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Protractor is a tool for testing Angular JS web sites. It's quite like the Selenium so it is not anyhow connected with your issue.

Your issue is connected with a testing framework that you use. 
What happens now is your screenshot is probably taken at the end of a test (after scenario/after test) or even after test suite.

What you need is to take the screenshot right after test step or even right after a test failure. I guess after your test failure some teardown actions are performed. The thing is you need to take a screenshot before those actions. This way it will be taken in time.

Comment: thanks @Denis Koreyba for the valuable suggestions/view.